# Serialization - Relative image path instead of absolute

Tags: serialization, fabricjs

When I searialize my canvas, I'd like to have my images sources as relative path instead of absolutes
Is there anything I can do for that ?

Thanks !­­

Comment: how your current path looks like? and what you want it to be?

Comment: Like : file://localpath 
I'm using fabric through electron

Comment: there is no native functionality for this. you need to do it manually.

Comment: Can I override this behavior in a any way?

Comment: yes you can but, that would be a complex approach.

Comment: So what do you recommend? After getting Json from canvas I have to loop over each images to change this path?

Comment: yes that would be an easier one

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll do that